# OpenCV Image Comparison for Surface Damage detection

Tags: opencv

We are planning to create a surface damage detection prototype for ceramic tiles with surface discoloration as a specific damage through the use of OpenCV. We would like to know what method should we consider using. We are new into developing these types of object recognition/object tracking programs. We've read about methods such as the Histogram method and the one where the Hue saturation value was being tracked, but still we are confused.

Also, we would like to know whether it is possible to detect the Hue saturation value of an object without the use of track bars.

Any relevant and helpful response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in sequence:

1) find tile region. Use corners detector, hough lines, etc.

2) find SIFT (or other descriprors) and recognize what image must be on this tile (find it in you tiles images database).

3) align images carefully. For example find homograpy between found in DB image and image of tile from camera (using SIFT features).

4) find color distance between every pixel in tile image from camera and tile image from database.

5) threshold differences by some value -> get problematic regions

And think about lighting. You have to provide equal lighting conditions for you measurements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response:) It is a great help! I was just wondering if this sequence can be done in real time?

Comment: I think you can start from opencv's standard example: video_homography.cpp which is in opencv\samples\cpp\ folder. Try it, i think it'll help to begin ( it works in real time :) ). Descriptor matching is slow, but you can use GPU for speed it up 10-20 times.

Comment: Again, thank you for your response. We are considering to use a kinect sensor instead of a web camera, (i'm sorry if i didn't mentioned it earlier), will this standard example work with whatever camera/sensor we choose to use?

Comment: I think yes, you can use it (it uses only image), but it will obviously not optimal for kinect. It'll be better if you find plane interpolation (for example using least squares method, RANSAC, or something like this). Then get tile corner points, put it on found plane (they will be not far from it). All other steps will not change.